# Can one hard code a blacklist function in a solana smart contract?

Tags: web3.js

Pls can i? I'd really need to know because it'd help me a lot if I could get to blacklist intentional buyers that spend big buys early into my project

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
const BLACKLIST: [&'static str; 1] =
    ["2X8Y9Z1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9j1k2L3M4N5P6Q7R8S9T1U2V3W4X5Y6Z7"];

pub fn init_player(ctx: Context<InitPlayer>) -> Result<()> {
    if BLACKLIST.contains(&ctx.accounts.signer.key().to_string().as_str()) {
        return Err(GameErrorCode::Blacklisted.into());
    }
    init_player::init_player(ctx)
}
```

Basically check if the signer is black listed and then throw an error.